# Maintain Activity State with two Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-state

We have and Android App that contains two Activities MainActivity and PageTwo. In the MainActivity we have an EditText widget set to accept number input only and a Button that goes to the next activity with the aid of an Intent. On the second activity PageTwo we have a Button that returns the user to the MainActivity with an Intent. When we enter a value in the EditText field and make the trip from the MainActivity to PageTwo activity and back the value is seemingly erased unless you use the device (emulator) back button. I am trying to maintain the Activity State of this one EditText variable

code snippets

```
 EditText ETage;
 int vAGE;
 static final String V_AGE = "vAGE"; //KeyValue Pair

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putInt(V_AGE,vAGE);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

//@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    vAGE = savedInstanceState.getInt(V_AGE);
    ETage.setText(String.valueOf(vAGE));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //if(savedInstanceState != null){
        //vAGE = savedInstanceState.getChar(V_AGE);
    //}
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ETage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);
```

Comment: From what I understand, you've started a new instance of the first Activity on top of the second one. To "go back" to the actual first activity, you call `finish()` from the second.

Comment: @cricket_007 the finish() did the trick thanks I only have 10 rep points so not sure I can give you credit What bugs me is this same question was ask with the directions to use the intent

Comment: Show your pagetwo code for come back to MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go back to previous Activity why you are calling intent? just simply write `onBackPressed();` inside `onClick`

**Example**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

or if you really wanted to use intent you can always use `finish()`.

**Example**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(PageTwo.this, MainActivity.class);            
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: so do I keep my two Bundles or can that be deleted

Comment: if you use first method. delete them. and if you use second one you need to keep them.

Comment: puohit tried your code with the intent and finish it fails if we just enter finish() without the intent all is good

Comment: calling finish() is  same as first method i have stated.

Comment: You should remove intent part from your second example mainly because it'll just create a new instance of `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

In `PageTwo` second activity don't return to `MainActivity` with an intent. Simply, do following in button click:

```
super.onBackPressed(); // this instead of intent to start MainActivity
```

Comment: tried to enter that line of code under an onClick(View v) with no results error can't resolve method

Comment: @James_Duh Thats unlikely, what activity class are you using...? Btw, you can solve the issue with `finish()` too.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(PageTwo.this,MainActivity.class)

Comment: @James_Duh No, you said you are getting 'can't resolve method' error in `super.onBackPressed()`. So, I was asking what `Activity` class are you extending?

Comment: not extending the Activity Class we are extending the AppCompatActivity I want to keep the action bar do not know how to do that if we extend only Activity

Comment: @James_Duh Thats what I wanted to know...Just remember that `AppCompatActivity` is also derived from `Activity` class. So, it should have `onBackPressed()` method. You said there was a 'can't resolve method' error? That shouldn't really be there. Can you recheck?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you can do like this in second page:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

Intent intent = new   Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: This will likely not change anything. Since, on back press, he's already getting proper results